# How do I except specific kinds of pymysql.err.InternalErrors, not just all of them?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am writing a function to that can add a new table to my database. The problem I am having is when the table already exist I get the error message:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1050, "Table 'doesthiswork' already exists")
```

So I added an except to my code which works but it is excepting all Internal errors. How do I get my code to except the specific error which I am assuming is 1050 not Internal Errors in general?

```
import pymysql

def CreateTable(Host,User,Password,DataBase,TableName):

    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(
                           host = Host,
                           user = User,
                           password= Password,
                           db = DataBase
                          )
        a = conn.cursor()
        tblName = TableName
        sql = 'CREATE TABLE'+" "+ tblName + '(try varchar(128));'

        a.execute(sql)

    except pymysql.err.InternalError: 
        print (tblName + " " + 'already exist')
```

The above code works, but as stated earlier if a different type of internal error surfaced it would just except that as table already exist not the actual error itself.

Comment: Please accept the @AChampion's answer as he was the first who proposed the idea of reading codes from the exception object. Would be more fair. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted the other answer, I liked your idea of having dict() that is going to work really well for me thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the exception to a variable and test the specific error codes, e.g.:

```
except pymysql.err.InternalError as e:
    code, msg = e.args
    if code == 1050:
        print(tblName, 'already exists')
```

Though you can probably just `print(msg)`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to hardcode the code values, they are available in the [`pymysql.constants.ER` module](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/constants/ER.py). And you can have a mapping between error codes and error messages, which can help to scale this approach to handling more errors without multiplying the if/else blocks:

```
from pymysql.constants import ER

error_codes = {
   ER.TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR: "Table already exists",
   ER.ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: "Access denied"
}

try:
    # ...
except pymysql.err.InternalError as e:
    code, msg = e.args
    print(error_codes.get(code, msg))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional catch-all "except" like so:

```
try:
    # your code here
except pymysql.err.InternalError:
    print('already exists')
except:
    print('catch-all exception!')
```